# "copy rotation" bone starts already with a rotation

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I wish to rotate the foot separate in global coordinates in Graph editor. To do this I added a controller bone that is geometricly straight.
Now I added "Copy rotation" to the foot bone. But the foot already rotates even tho the controller bone has not yet rotated.

[image: foot should be fore warts]

[image: foot rotates even tho the contoller bones does not yet]

How can I add a 'zero' position for the controller bone of the foot regarding the adding of the rotation to the foot bone?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may instead want to use the Child Of constraint, which has options for setting inverse and copying position as well, but behaves as you would expect just adding the constraint and disabling the Location and Scale options.

[image: Child Of]

[image: Rotated]

But if you want to use Copy Rotation, setting the Target space to "Local Space (Owner Orientation)" and Owner space to "Local Space" seems to do the trick:

[image]